# intel SPDK ioat example fail to run

Tags: linux, intel

I am new in the intel SPDK and meet some problem when I run the example code.

I setup the BIOS as [this page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-memcpy-using-spdk-and-ioat-dma-engine) said.

> Intel® Hyper-Threading Technology off
>
> Intel SpeedStep® technology enabled
>
> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology disabled

then I git clone from [this page](https://github.com/spdk/spdk) and run all the command. The test command **./test/unit/unittest.sh** return **All unit tests passed**.

But when I run the example examples/ioat/verify/verify , it return

> EAL: 24 hugepages of size 1073741824 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found for that size
>
> Starting SPDK v18.10-pre / DPDK 18.05.0 initialization...
>
> [ DPDK EAL parameters: verify --no-shconf -c 0x1 --legacy-mem --file-prefix=spdk_pid3170 ]
>
> EAL: Detected 16 lcore(s)
>
> EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
>
> EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/spdk_pid3170/mp_socket
>
> EAL: 24 hugepages of size 1073741824 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found 
>   for that size
>
> EAL: Probing VFIO support...
>
> User configuration:
>
> Run time:       10 seconds
>
> Core mask:      0x1
>
> Queue depth:    32
>
> Not enough ioat channels found. Check that ioat channels are bound
>   to uio_pci_generic or vfio-pci.  scripts/setup.sh can help with this.

and scripts/setup.sh status shows

> Hugepages
>
> node     hugesize     free /  total
>
> node0   1048576kB       24 /     24
>
> node0      2048kB        0 /    800
>
> node1   1048576kB        0 /      0
>
> node1      2048kB        0 /    224
>
> NVMe devices
>
> BDF        Numa Node   Driver name     Device name
>
> I/OAT DMA
>
> BDF        Numa Node   Driver Name
>
> virtio
>
> BDF        Numa Node   Driver Name     Device Name

My hardware is:

> linux kernel version 4.15.7
>   with ioatdma compile as module
>
> CPU intel Xeon E5-2695
>
> chipset C612

It would be great help if somebody could give me some advises or send me some website about SPDK!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `./scripts/setup.sh` (with no parameters). If there will be no `ioat` devices under `I/OAT DMA` section you can't run this app. Also there is no `hugetlbfs` mount points.